# Is it possible to post status updates to Twitter using Firebase?

Tags: twitter, firebase, firebase-authentication

does anyone know if the new Google's Firebase can post tweets to Twitter?

I checked Google's Firebase website and it mentions that users can authenticate using their services. Once this authentication and authorization is done, I should have the required keys to access Twitter's API.

However, I was wondering if the Google's Firebase (Android SDK), can post tweets using one of its classes or methods automatically (without having to send an independent REST request from the Android app).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no API in Firebase that posts to Twitter.

But you can get the access token when the user signs in and use that to post to twitter in your own code. For more info, see https://firebase.google.com/support/guides/firebase-web#get_the_access_token_numbered

Answer (score 0):

According to 
[firebase.auth.TwitterAuthProvider](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.TwitterAuthProvider#setCustomParameters) one can store the access token and secret to access the twitter APIs. Though [Get the access token](https://firebase.google.com/support/guides/firebase-web#get_the_access_token_numbered) there is an explicit warning of Twitter API not directly invokable! The authdata structure will return everything needed for the twitter API. And then you need to use Android OAuth2 to set the proper parameters with the different Twitter APIs.